# Count number of " date hour minutes" before two datetime points

Tags: python, pandas

I have code that will give me the cumulative number of patients in a location by hour between two date/time points. However, I want to tweak this code to show the data by minutes.

```
Datatable: 
ID          ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME          DISPOSITION_DATE
1           2021-11-07 08:35:00     2021-11-07 17:58:00
2           2021-11-07 13:16:00     2021-11-08 02:52:00
3           2021-11-07 15:12:00     2021-11-07 21:08:00


Desired output:
ID          DATE_HOUR_MIN_IN_ED        
1           2021-11-07 08:35:00         
1           2021-11-07 08:36:00         
1           2021-11-07 08:37:00 
.....        
1           2021-11-07 17:58:00          
...
2           2021-11-07 13:16:00          
2           2021-11-07 13:17:00          
2           2021-11-07 13:18:00
```

I suspect I need to change what I have FREQ equal to but am not sure what to put.

Code:

```
   TEST['Date']=[pd.date_range(a,b , freq='H') for a , b in zip(TEST.ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,TEST.DISPOSITION_DATE)]
    s=TEST[['Date','ID']].explode('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

[Create date/hour variable for each hour between two datetime variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929123/create-date-hour-variable-for-each-hour-between-two-datetime-variables)

Answer (score 1):

From [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)
"freq: str or DateOffset, default ‘D’
Frequency strings can have multiples, e.g. ‘5H’. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) for a list of frequency aliases."

"Offset aliases
A number of string aliases are given to useful common time series frequencies. We will refer to these aliases as offset aliases."

```
(...)
H hourly frequency
T, min minutely frequency
S secondly frequency
(...)
```